# Asp.net Identity UserManager error:UserName is null

Tags: asp.net-identity-2

UserManager CreateAsyncy gives error: UserName cannot be empty or null.

Below is my code snippet:

```
    var contractor = new Contractor()
                {
                    UserName = contractorModel.UserName,
                    Email = contractorModel.Email,
                    EmailConfirmed = true,
                    SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()


                };
               var result =  await UserManager.CreateAsync(contractor,"Passw0rd!");
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by UserName = contractorModel.Email;